# Can I alter control layout on the fly?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Is there a way to alter a window or dialog from a vertical layout to a horizontal layout?

e.g. from this (narrow tall window)

```
A: -------  
B: -------  
C: --------  
D: --------
```

To this (square window)

```
A:-------- C:-------
B:-------- D:--------
```

To this (wide window).

```
A:------ B:------- C:-------- D:---------
```

As I resize the window?
A, B, C, D are edit boxes or comboboxes etc

Obviously, I can use a pagecontrol with 3 (or more) pages and invisible tabs and alternate between these, but I'm hoping to do this without such duplication.

I'm hoping for a solution that does not require me to write code.

Comment: Of course you can do this. You can change the position of controls inside an `OnResize` event handler.

Comment: Looks like a TFlowPanel can help you achieve that.

Comment: You can override a container `AlignControls` and adjust the layout. same way as done by `TFlowPanel` and `TGridPanel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example uses a `TFlowPanel`.  It is added to the form with `Align` set to `alClient`.  Four `TEdit` controls are added to the `TFlowPanel`.  When resizing the form they automatically realign themselves in the way you've described.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Changing the `FlowStyle` property allows you to customize the layout behaviour.  Above shows the default `fsLeftRightTopBottom` giving:

```
 A:-------- B:-------
 C:-------- D:--------
```

in the square window.  Using `fsTopBottomLeftRight` will give you the layout in the question, however.

```
 A:-------- C:-------
 B:-------- D:--------
```